# Basic sample program of Spen SDK throws Run time exception

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

I am writing a basic android app involving Spen SDK. My XML file is:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/canvas_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView
            android:id="@+id/canvas_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />
        <com.samsung.sdraw.SettingView
            android:id="@+id/setting_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As soon as I write this XML, some error pops up in my Preview Panel. The screen-shot is attached below:
[image]

The error is:-

```
Rendering Problems:  
The following classes could not be instantiated:  
- com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView (Open Class, Show Exception)  
- com.samsung.sdraw.SettingView (Open Class, Show Exception)  
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in   the IDE

Exception Details                   (<-----with regard to com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView class)
Write access not allowed during rendering   (\mnt\sdcard\android\data\null\serial)   

at com.android.ide.common.rendering.RenderSecurityException.create(RenderSecurityException.java:52)      
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.RenderSecurityManager.checkWrite (RenderSecurityManager.java:544)       
at java.io.File.mkdir(File.java:1305)       
at java.io.File.mkdirs(File.java:1337)       
at com.samsung.sdraw.z.a(SourceFile:23)       
at com.samsung.sdraw.z.a(SourceFile:15)     
at com.samsung.sdraw.Setting.a(SourceFile:470)     
at com.samsung.sdraw.Setting.<init>(SourceFile:261)     
at com.samsung.sdraw.ModeContext.<init>(SourceFile:73)     
at com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView.h(SourceFile:735)     
at com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView.<init>(SourceFile:606)     
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)    
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)

Diagnostic info for Studio bug report:  
 Failed path: \mnt\sdcard\android\data\null\serial   
Normal temp dir: C:\Users\avinash\AppData\Local\Temp\     
Normalized temp dir: C:\Users\avinash\AppData\Local\Temp     
Canonical temp dir: C:\Users\avinash\AppData\Local\Temp os.name: Windows 8 os.version: 6.2 java.runtime.version: 1.7.0_55-b13 


Exception details        (<-----with regard to com.samsung.sdraw.SettingView class)  

java.lang.NullPointerException   at com.samsung.sdraw.bx.<init>(SourceFile:84)  
   at com.samsung.sdraw.AbstractSettingView.a(SourceFile:685)     
at com.samsung.sdraw.AbstractSettingView.<init>(SourceFile:648)     
at com.samsung.sdraw.SettingView.<init>(SourceFile:151)     
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)     
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
```

Can anybodu help me with these error?

Update:
When I run the program, the logcat gives the following warnings once the debugger has settled:

```
06-10 12:04:58.916  31170-31323/com.example.myapplication4.app E/CB::BeautifyNative﹕ WARNING: Could not load libjni_secime natives  
06-10 12:04:58.916  31170-31323/com.example.myapplication4.app W/dalvikvm﹕ No implementation found for native Lcom/bst/HwBeautify/BeautifyNative;.nativeCBInitEngine:()I  
06-10 12:04:58.916  31170-31323/com.example.myapplication4.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fec700)  
06-10 12:04:58.921  31170-31323/com.example.myapplication4.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13335  
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:   com.bst.HwBeautify.BeautifyNative.nativeCBInitEngine:()I  
            at com.bst.HwBeautify.BeautifyNative.nativeCBInitEngine(Native Method)  
            at com.bst.HwBeautify.BeautifyNative.cbInitEngine(SourceFile:107)  
            at com.bst.HwBeautify.BeautifyManager.b(SourceFile:87)  
            at com.bst.HwBeautify.BeautifyManager.a(SourceFile:85)  
            at com.bst.HwBeautify.BeautifyManager$1.run(SourceFile:64)  
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)  
06-10 12:04:59.891  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 925K, 22% free 14857K/18952K, paused 13ms, total 14ms  
06-10 12:04:59.901  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 23.625MB for 6317296-byte allocation  
06-10 12:04:59.916  31170-31179/com.example.myapplication4.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 17% free 21027K/25124K, paused 13ms, total 13ms  
06-10 12:04:59.931  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 17% free 21025K/25124K, paused 9ms, total 9ms  
06-10 12:04:59.946  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 29.648MB for 6317296-byte allocation  
06-10 12:04:59.956  31170-31179/com.example.myapplication4.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 14% free 27194K/31296K, paused 10ms, total 10ms  
06-10 12:05:00.181  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app E/ViewSystem﹕ ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.  
06-10 12:05:00.191  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/android/data/com.example.myapplication4.app/serial/1125509560/sprites.raw: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)  
06-10 12:05:00.196  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)  
06-10 12:05:00.196  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)  
06-10 12:05:00.196  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)  
06-10 12:05:00.196  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at com.samsung.sdraw.AbstractModeContext.a(SourceFile:182)  
06-10 12:05:00.196  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at com.samsung.sdraw.AbstractModeContext.serializeContext(SourceFile:143)  
06-10 12:05:00.201  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView.b(SourceFile:7577)  
06-10 12:05:00.201  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView.onDetachedFromWindow(SourceFile:641)  
06-10 12:05:00.201  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:13064)  
06-10 12:05:00.201  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2798)  
06-10 12:05:00.201  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2798)  
06-10 12:05:00.201  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2798)  
06-10 12:05:00.206  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2798)  
06-10 12:05:00.206  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2798)  
06-10 12:05:00.206  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3368)  
06-10 12:05:00.206  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5978)  
06-10 12:05:00.206  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die(ViewRootImpl.java:5961)  
06-10 12:05:00.206  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:378)  
06-10 12:05:00.211  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:328)  
06-10 12:05:00.211  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:88)  
06-10 12:05:00.211  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3677)  
06-10 12:05:00.211  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:165)  
06-10 12:05:00.211  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)  
06-10 12:05:00.211  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
06-10 12:05:00.216  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)  
06-10 12:05:00.216  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)  
06-10 12:05:00.216  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
06-10 12:05:00.216  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)  
06-10 12:05:00.216  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)  
06-10 12:05:00.216  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)  
06-10 12:05:00.221  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  
06-10 12:05:00.221  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)  
06-10 12:05:00.221  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)  
06-10 12:05:00.221  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)  
06-10 12:05:00.226  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)  
06-10 12:05:00.226  31170-31170/com.example.myapplication4.app W/System.err﹕ ... 29 more
```

Comment: Does the app actually _run_ on your device?

Comment: It shows the first screen and then immediately crashes....The error is not compile time, its run time

Comment: Did you add the Samsung Mobile SDK correctly? What is the stack trace from LogCat?

Comment: To add the SDK I copied the libspen23.jar, libspen23_multiwindow.jar and armeabi directory to the lib directory of my project. Then I right clicked on the jars and added libspen23.jar and libspen23_multiwindow.jar as libraries...Also I have updated the logcat in the question