# including spen-sdk into android studio

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

Can anyone tell me the correct step by step way to include Spen-SDK into Android studio? The way I am including it allows the Samsung classes to be accessed from within the app but is leading to some weird problems(I have mentioned the problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133987/basic-sample-program-of-spen-sdk-throws-run-time-exception)) which no one else seems to face.

Mentioning the steps here or directing me to the site which contains it would suffice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just copy the two .jar files from spen-sdk.zip folder and paste into the libs folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to is to use the SDK Manager and add it there so your project can find it:

http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000182L